# How to include xml files in app directory in Nativescript webpack

Tags: webpack, nativescript

In my application I have two main screens for two types of users and a login page. When a user opens the app I check what is the type of the user, and based on the user type I open a specific `app-root.xml` file.

**app.js**

```
let currentLogin = appSettings.getString("login", "nothing");
if (currentLogin === 'customer') {
    application.run({ moduleName: "app-root-home" });
}
else if (currentLogin === 'shop') {
    application.run({ moduleName: "app-root-shop" });
}
else {
    application.run({ moduleName: "app-root" });
}
```

I have three different XML files in my `app` directory (`app-root`, `app-root-home` & `app-root-shop`). each of them has a different frame wrapped in different layouts.

When I execute without Webpack everything works fine, but when I enable `Webpack` from sidekick, if the following statement is executed `application.run({ moduleName: "app-root-home" });` I receive an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '_domid' of undefined`.

I tried to decompile the application and see the `bundle.js` file and I found that webpack didn't add `app-root-home.xml` nor `app-root-shop.xml`. Only `app-root.xml` was there.

I'm using nativescript sidekick and I'm building my project on cloud; I don't type command lines a lot, the cloud does that for me.

My [`nativescript-dev-webpack`](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack) dev version is `0.19.0`.

I'm developing in `JS`.

I tried to find a solution on github for similar issues like mine, and to be able to include `xml` files in the `app` directory, and all the solutions included modifications in `bundle-config.js` which I don't have in my project.

It looks like in new versions of `webpack` the `bundle-config.js` file doesn't exist anymore in the `app` directory, instead it exists in the same plugin folders. [Reference](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/upgrading-to-nativescript-webpack-0.12.0)

I only have `webpack.config.js` in my `app` directory, so I need to know to can I add the xml files to it in JS, but I couldn't find a way to do this.

How can I include all `xml` files in `app` directory in the latest version of webpack plugin to my application and run on sidekick.

Comment: Does it still throw error if you remove the if conditions and directly run `application.run({ moduleName: "app-root-home" });`?

Comment: Yes, it does.Looks like only `app-root.xml` file is the only `xml` file included regardless of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a separated `app-root-home.xml` & `app-root-shop.xml` files, you can create two new pages(`app-root-home` & `app-root-shop`). For each page, nativescript will create `*-page.js`, `*-view-model.js` & `*-page.xml` files, and webpack won't delete those files when you release a version.

After creating the two new pages, you can include the `*-page.xml` files instead of the `app-root-home` & `app-root-shop` xml files.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem temporarily by putting the other `app-root` files in new folders of their names as the below tree shows:

```
  app
    |-- app-root.xml
    |-- app-root-home
    |   |-- app-root-home-page.js        //empty JS file
    |   |-- app-root-home-view-model.js  //empty JS file
    |   `-- app-root-home-page.xml
    `-- app-root-shop
        |-- app-root-shop-page.js        //empty JS file
        |-- app-root-shop-view-model.js  //empty JS file
        `-- app-root-shop-page.xml
```

and in my `app.js` file:

```
let currentLogin = appSettings.getString("login", "nothing");
if (currentLogin === 'customer') {
    application.run({ moduleName: "app-root-home/app-root-home-page" });
}
else if (currentLogin === 'shop') {
    application.run({ moduleName: "app-root-shop/app-root-shop-page" });
}
else {
    application.run({ moduleName: "app-root" });
}
```

This is not the answer to my question; it's just a fast fix.